# Need to change the Colour of each menu heading. - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, themes

I have a website:

http://cancersurvivorshipireland.com/cancersurvivorshipireland.com/wordpress/
(temp address)

but I have all the menu topics in the header the same colour, they are all green. I am trying to get them all different colours.

eg. Home = green, News = red, Blog = yellow. but have absolutely no idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [CSS nth child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) as follows:

```css
#menu-default li:nth-child(1) a { 
    color: green;
}
#menu-default li:nth-child(2) a { 
    color: red;
}
#menu-default li:nth-child(3) a { 
    color: yellow;
}
#menu-default li:nth-child(4) a { 
    color: orange;
}
#menu-default li:nth-child(5) a { 
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of those menu items have a distinct id and a matching class, *i.e.*, `li.menu-item-39` is also `li#menu-item-39`. You can use CSS to target these ids or classes, whichever you are more comfortable with.

```
li.menu-item-39 > a { /* Home */
  color: green;
}
li.menu-item-43 > a { /* News */
  color: red;
}
li.menu-item-47 > a { /* Blog */
  color: yellow;
}
```

**Edited to address other answers:** You can use the `:nth-child` pseudo-class to do this, but that will only work in browsers that support CSS3.

Comment: I think it should be noted that while this solution has greater browser compatibility, it could be less flexible than `nth-child`. If the user changes the menu items at some point then the `menu-item-*` class will change. ie `menu-item-46` => `menu-item-67`.

Comment: Good point, hungerstar. One can shim the `:nth-child` pseudo-class by using the following CSS2 selectors: `#menu-default li:first-child > a` is equivalent to `#menu-default li:nth-child(1) > a`, `#menu-default li:first-child + li > a` is equivalent to `#menu-default li:nth-child(2) > a`, `#menu-default li:first-child + li + li > a` is equivalent to `#menu-default li:nth-child(3) > a`, _etc._

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) on the list element. Add this to your css file

```css
#menu-default > li:nth-child(1) > a { color: green; }
#menu-default > li:nth-child(2) > a { color: red; }
#menu-default > li:nth-child(3) > a { color: yellow; }
#menu-default > li:nth-child(4) > a { color: white; }
#menu-default > li:nth-child(5) > a { color: orange; }
```

Answer (score -2):

You would need to get into the navigation.php file I'm presuming and add css id parameters to each and then give them any entry in styles.css to assign the color.

If you're not familiar with editing the files or changing code it's not an easy fix.

Here's some css code:

```
#menu-default > li:nth-child(1) > a { color: green; }
#menu-default > li:nth-child(2) > a { color: red; }
#menu-default > li:nth-child(3) > a { color: yellow; }
#menu-default > li:nth-child(4) > a { color: white; }
#menu-default > li:nth-child(5) > a { color: orange; }
```

Comment: this is not a difficult fix if you have access to your css files or can edit via the WordPress admin. Not sure why you're mentioning navigation.php either. WordPress adds ids to each `li` for you. You're making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: its is if you have no experience editing WP files. And you're assuming that he has a properly coded theme.