# No matter what I try the header won't change color

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, colors, header

i have the following website

http://cancersurvivorshipireland.com/cancersurvivorshipireland.com/wordpress/

and I'm trying to change the header menu color. I have previously changed the colour for the menu items themselves from code that someone provided here and it was very helpful however no matter what I do I can't change that dirty blue color to something nicer.

I have tried various types of code:

```
top-header {
    background-color: white;
}

header {
    background-color: white;
}

.sf-menu {       
 position: relative;         
 padding: 0;         
 width: 100%;        
 border-bottom: 3px solid #e9e9e9;       
 background: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a caching issue. I can change the bg color of `.top-header` using developer tools and it changes with no problem.

Comment: Where is `.sf-menu` on your page?

Comment: Please close up this question if it is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you visit the [actual stylesheet that's doing the overriding](http://cancersurvivorshipireland.com/cancersurvivorshipireland.com/wordpress/?custom-css=1&csblog=1&cscache=6&csrev=17), you'll see that it's a custom stylesheet that's being generated by theme options. It doesn't even exist on the server as an actual `.css` file. It's also the last styles being called on the page.

Rather than editing a different CSS stylesheet and using `!important` to override this, you're better off updating it (or even removing this, if possible) from the WP Admin theme options.

Also, as mentioned by the (now deleted?) other answer, you need to make sure you're prefixing the `.top-header` class with a `.`. Your question doesn't currently show this.

Comment: Call me stupid, but where are you seeing this stylesheet override for .top-header ? When I inspect with firebug, i see .top-header {
    background-color: #34495e;
} coming from the standard style sheet... (under the css/ folder) - again, the OP has posted the CSS without a leading fullstop for both classes - that will never apply to a class - is it a typo? two lines? I suspect not.

Comment: [This](http://cancersurvivorshipireland.com/cancersurvivorshipireland.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/calm/css/style.css) is the stylesheet you're referring to, which is being called before [this](http://cancersurvivorshipireland.com/cancersurvivorshipireland.com/wordpress/?custom-css=1&csblog=1&cscache=6&csrev=17), which is being generated by the theme itself. If you observe the standard stylesheet, you're right about the color being `#34495e;`. But the header color **isn't** `#34495e;`, it's `#000`, as defined by the second sheet.

Comment: The second set of styles I linked to also contains the answer from [this other question from the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413666/need-to-change-the-colour-of-each-menu-heading-wordpress)

Comment: @Damien ... Ha, never. Stack Overflow already has too much of that going around.